# Informix select for update with order by

Tags: sql, informix

In ESQL/C I need to do a statement like this (I know that "order by" clause is not allowed in a "select ... for update")

```
SELECT FIRST 1 fd_foglio, fd_box_cod_soc, NVL(fd_id_subfoglio, 0)
FROM informix.foglioddt     
WHERE     
  fd_box_data_all = TO_CHAR(CURRENT YEAR TO DAY, '%iy%m%d') AND         
  fd_box_cod_soc = '*'
ORDER BY fd_foglio DESC;

EXEC SQL
        OPEN ifx_cursor_foglioddt_for_pending_crates;

EXEC SQL
        FETCH ifx_cursor_foglioddt_for_pending_crates 
        INTO :fd_foglio, :fd_box_cod_soc, :local_fd_id_subfoglio;
```

in which I need an "order by" clause inside a "select for update" — I know that isn't allowed — in order to use a cursor successively to increment the field fd_id_subfogli (after I have used it in another part of the code) with a statement like:

```
UPDATE informix.foglioddt SET fd_id_subfoglio = :new_value WHERE 
CURRENT OF ifx_cursor_foglioddt_for_pending_crates
```

How can I rewrite the previous code in order to select only the first ordered record and update a field in it?

Comment: What is the primary key on the `foglioddt` table?  It looks like `fd_foglio` is probably one component, but maybe `fd_id_subfoglio` is more or less part of it too — except that the NVL implies it can be NULL, and primary keys can't contain null-allowing columns.  If it weren't for the NVL, it would be straight-forward.  If there's a NULL in `fd_id_subfoglio`, does it mean there's a single row for the `fd_foglio` value?

Answer (score 0):

The necessary information isn't in the question, but making a semi-educated guess, the `foglioddt` table has a UNIQUE constraint on columns `fd_foglio` and `fd_id_subfoglio`, but the latter can be NULL (in which case, Informix only allows one row in the table with a given `fd_foglio` value and a NULL `fd_id_subfoglio`).

Assuming that if there are any rows for a given `fd_foglio` value where the `fd_id_subfoglio` value is not null, then all the rows for that given `fd_foglio` value have a non-null value for the `fd_id_subfoglio` value, you could rephrase the UPDATE as:

```
UPDATE informix.foglioddt SET fd_id_subfoglio = :new_value
 WHERE fd_foglio = :fd_foglio
   AND (fd_id_subfoglio = :local_fd_id_subfoglio OR
        fd_id_subfoglio IS NULL)
```

The first part of the OR condition deals with the normal case, where you've got both values that make up the primary key, and you simply change the identified row.  The second part of the OR condition deals with the case where the only row in the table has `fd_id_subfoglio` set null.

Clearly, if my interpretation of the data structure is incorrect, then this won't work.  The solution will then be to select the values from the primary key columns so that you can update using the primary key to identify the row to be updated — that's why primary keys are important!  They're the way you can address individual rows by a set of values.  Indexes on primary keys are also important to speed up such access (and to enforce uniqueness).